# How to reinstall Azure SDK

Tags: azure

I have problems with opening azure project (created using v. 1.6). And I want to down-grade or reinstall Azure SDK (on Windows XP + Visual Studio 2010). How to do this?

Using Web Installer, Install button is disabled:
[image]

Comment: Did you try going to "Add/Remove programs" -> Windows Azure SDK -> Remove/Uninstall ?

Comment: Yes, it is absent in "Add/Remove programs", so maybe there were issues while installing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you sure you wanted to install Azure SDK on Windows XP? The WebPI installer recognize the OS and disable the "Install" button is OS is not supported. And It is certain that you have no SDK installed on this machine thats why it is not visible in "Add/Remove Programs"

So  if you want to use Windows Azure SDK (even without WebPI) using the link [here](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=35448), still you would need a support OS as described here:

- Supported operating systems: Windows 7, Windows 8, Windows Server 2008 R2, Windows Server 2008 Service Pack 2, Windows Server 2012
- You sure can use VS2010 SP1 with Azure SDK